# typescript Object is possibly null when getting files from event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

I am trying to make a typescript + react fileinput component.
However I'm getting typescript error 'Object is possibly null'.
I have googled but couldn't find solution for this problem.
How can I fix this problem without disabling typescript null check.

I'm getting errors on e.target.files[0]!

Here is the code below

```
import React from 'react';


    export default function ImageUpload() {
      const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState<File | string>('fileurl');
      const [imagePreviewUrl, setImagePreviewUrl] = React.useState<string | undefined | ArrayBuffer | null>();

      const fileChangedHandler = (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]!);

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = () => {
          setImagePreviewUrl(reader.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]!);
      };

      const submit = () => {
        const fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('file', selectedFile);
      };

      let imagePreview = (<div className="previewText image-container">Please select an Image for Preview</div>);
      if (imagePreviewUrl) {
        imagePreview = (
          <div className="image-container">
            <img src={imagePreviewUrl} alt="icon" width="200" />
            {' '}
          </div>
        );
      }

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input type="file" name="avatar" onChange={fileChangedHandler} />
          <button type="button" onClick={submit}> Upload </button>
          { imagePreview }
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`HTMLInputElement` has a built-in property `files` that is typeof `FileList | null`.

> ```
> files: FileList | null;
> ```

Simply secure the possibility that `files` is `null`.

```
if (!e.target.files) return;
```

At the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 8):

Guys this is the proper way of handling this issue:

```
            e.target.files instanceof FileList
              ? reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]) : 'handle exception'
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

From the code, I suspect that `e.target` is nullable. You could modify `e.target.files[0]!` to `e.target!.files[0]!`, which will make error go away because you will essentially tell the Typescript compiler that "it will not be null, trust me". But instead, I would advise to handle the null case properly - check for null or undefined and do something appropriate, depending on your app logic.

Comment: Suggestion a null assertion where there is a high probability of `null` is a bad taste.

Comment: Agreed, that's what my answer is essentially saying as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!e.target.files || e.target.files.length === 0) {
      // you can display the error to the user
      console.error("Select a file");
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code it worked like this: I created a variable that received the HTML event, then created a variable that received all the event files and used the 'item' functionality at index 0, and then I was able to access the file

```js
const handleSetFileName = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const files = event.target.files;
  setFileName(files?.item(0)?.name);
};
```

Comment: I get a TS error on `ChangeEvent`: `Cannot find name 'ChangeEvent'.ts(2304)
type ChangeEvent = /*unresolved*/ any`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fileChangedHandler = (e) => {
  const sellectFile = e.target.file ? e.target.files[0] : null;

  if (selectfile) {
    setSelectedFile(selectfile);
  }
};
```

Comment: Add some code to explain your answer.