# 'e.target.files' is possibly 'null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file, events, react-tsx

In my input component I extract file content after input. [Took code from here](https://medium.com/@miniceo/front-end-shorts-how-to-read-content-from-the-file-input-in-react-17f49b293909)

Error occurred on the line of `onChange={e => handleFileChosen(e.target.files[0])}`, to be more accurate, ts underlines `e.target.files`.

Error message is `'e.target.files' is possibly 'null'`

And here is the code:

```
import styles from './Input.module.scss'
import { FileInputProps } from './FileInput.props';
import cn from 'classnames'
import { useState } from 'react';

export const FileInput = ({ ...props }: FileInputProps): JSX.Element => {
      const [fileContent, setFileContent] = useState<string>('')

      const handleFileChosen = (file: File) => {
            let fileReader = new FileReader()
            fileReader.onloadend = (e: Event) => {
                  const content = fileReader.result || ''
                  setFileContent(content.toString())
            }
            fileReader.readAsText(file)
      }

      return (
            <>
                  <input
                        type='file'
                        onChange={(e) => {handleFileChosen(e.target.files[0])}}
                  />
                  <p>{fileContent}</p>
            </>
      )
}
```

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573872/typescript-object-is-possibly-null-when-getting-files-from-event) SO page, but none of those solutions helped me

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in the code sandbox? 
as I'm not able to reproduce the error with your code

Comment: Didn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61750419/893780) provide you with a solution that you can apply to your code?

Comment: @robertklep for some reason no

Answer (score 1):

### Please review this code

```
import React, {ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const FileUploadComponent = () => {
    const [base64Data, setBase64Data] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const handleFileChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const files: FileList | null = e.target.files;
        const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            setBase64Data(reader.result as string)
        }
        reader.onerror = function () {
            setError("Error file not reading");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(files?.[0] as File);
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log(base64Data)
    }, [base64Data])

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                className={"form-control"}
                type={"file"}
                onChange={handleFileChange}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default FileUploadComponent;
```